# Status of Apache-Commons Commons-Functor

Tags: java, functional-programming, apache-commons, functor

When I look at the [commons-functor website](http://commons.apache.org/functor/) website, it appears to be out of sandbox state, but it also says [there is no official binary release](http://commons.apache.org/functor/download.html)?  But I thought I saw it in some Maven repository somewhere and can't find it now.  Does anyone know what the status is and whether there is an official binary release?  I suspect I am just poor at navigating the Commons website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the last development was three weeks ago ([see this](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/functor/)) and their "release notes" for 1.0 are just a skeleton ([see here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/functor/trunk/RELEASE-NOTES.txt?revision=1183729&view=co)).

A couple quick searches show that Apache Commons Lang used to have a package `org.apache.commons.lang.functor` - but this was removed some time ago, it seems (like [2003 or so](http://javacio.us/search?q=org%2Fapache%2Fcommons%2Flang%2Ffunctor%2FExecutorUtils%24WhileExecutor+more%3Ajar_files&inline=true))

As a side note, it appears that Apache Commons Collections has a package [`org.apache.commons.collections.functors`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/functors/package-summary.html) - but this might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think your links at the top are what I had seen before and somehow couldn't make my way back to, thanks for finding them.  I don't think it gives a definitive answer, but it helps.  And no, I'm not interested in the old functors package.

Comment: I'd still like to know something more definitive, but you gave me the most info. so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea what the release or maintenance state of this library is. My apologies.

But what i do know is that the world needs another functional programming library for Java like it needs a hole in the, er, head. Ozone layer? There are already quite a number in circulation - Functional Java, the functional parts of Guava, LambdaJ, and others - all doing much the same thing (or at least having overlapping bits doing much the same thing). What we need to do now is to start coalescing our attention around two or three of these libraries, developing common styles and idioms for using them.</rant>

At the company where i work, where there are a lot of big fans of functional programming, we seem to have settled on [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/), having had LambdaJ, Guava, and a couple of homebrewed functional frameworks in our codebase (and having rewritten bits of it in Scala!). That decision was made by people with deeper understanding of functional style than me, and before i joined the company, so i can't explain the reasoning, merely report that it was made. Functional Java is [actively developed](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/commits/master), and it's [in Maven](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.functionaljava%7Cfunctionaljava%7C3.0%7Cjar). I would urge you to have a look at it, and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, and honestly I am not looking to start using commons-functor myself.  My interest has to do with a library-agnostic open-source add-on I am writing that is meant to support whichever library other users choose, which already has support for Functional Java (if interested you can check it out in my profile, but I'll leave direct advertising out of this comment).

Comment: Ha! I came across Funcito the other day. Cool stuff. Please excuse my presumption in trying to scare you off.

Answer (score 1):

Commons Functor is heading toward it's first official release. You can give it a try by using the nightly snapshot from the Apache repository:

https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-functor/1.0-SNAPSHOT/